# Security Update for Laravel

Tags: laravel, security, github

I turned on Github dependabot and it has listed security vulnerabilities. I was told to use composer update package/laravel. I did this on my localhost and it says that there is nothing to modify in the lock file. I am using Visual Studio Code and it is not showing anything has been updated. I am new to this so it is a little confusing.

I have been searching the internet and all I can find is how to update Laravel to a newer version or the above command. Can someone give me tips on how to get my Laravel vulnerabilities fixed on my localhost and my Git repository.

Comment: What Laravel version you have?

Comment: add the content of composer.json to your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I looked at the comments and found the composer.json file in the directory. I realized I had not entered the directory when I ran the composer update. Once in the directory update went fine. Like I said this is new to me. Thanks for the help.